# PostgreSQL array_agg panfully slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I have a tables `calls` and `calls_statistics`. `calls` has a primary key `calls_id`, which is a foreign key in `calls_statistics`.

calls currently contains 16k entries.

When i run

```
SELECT c.*,
array_agg(cs.mean) AS statistics_means
FROM calls AS c
LEFT JOIN calls_statistics AS cs ON c.calls_id = cs.calls_id
GROUP BY c.calls_id
order by caller_id ASC, call_time ASC LIMIT 100;
```

The query takes about 622 ms

```
 Limit  (cost=11947.99..11948.24 rows=100 width=551) (actual time=518.921..518.941 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=11947.99..11989.07 rows=16429 width=551) (actual time=518.918..518.928 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: c.caller_id, c.call_time
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 126kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=11114.73..11320.09 rows=16429 width=551) (actual time=461.869..494.761 rows=16429 loops=1)
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=6234.65..10705.12 rows=81922 width=551) (actual time=79.171..257.498 rows=81922 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (cs.calls_id = c.calls_id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on calls_statistics cs  (cost=0.00..2627.22 rows=81922 width=12) (actual time=3.534..26.778 rows=81922 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=6029.29..6029.29 rows=16429 width=547) (actual time=75.578..75.578 rows=16429 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9370kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on calls c  (cost=0.00..6029.29 rows=16429 width=547) (actual time=13.806..42.446 rows=16429 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 622.537 ms
```

However, when I disable the `array_agg` and run the query it uses my indexes:

```
SELECT c.*,
cs.mean
FROM calls AS c
LEFT JOIN calls_statistics AS cs ON c.calls_id = cs.calls_id
order by caller_id ASC, call_time ASC LIMIT 100;
```

The query just takes 0.565ms!

```
 Limit  (cost=0.70..52.93 rows=100 width=551) (actual time=0.077..0.320 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.70..42784.95 rows=81922 width=551) (actual time=0.075..0.304 rows=100 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using calls_caller_id_call_time_calls_id_idx on calls c  (cost=0.29..22395.06 rows=16429 width=547) (actual time=0.042..0.091 rows=25 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using calls_stats_calls_idx on calls_statistics cs  (cost=0.42..1.18 rows=6 width=12) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=4 loops=25)
               Index Cond: (c.calls_id = calls_id)
 Total runtime: 0.565 ms
```

It can't be that just aggregating into arrays takes so much time? What am I doing wrong?

I am using Postgres 9.3.

Comment: I also noted that the `sort` expects 16429 rows but only gets 100. Somehow the query planner fooled itself..

Comment: You removed the `group by` in the second query.  That is probably dominating the time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah I know, but that's the whole point of my question.

Comment: The first query processes and aggregates 81922 rows and then discards 81822 of those. The second query only processes 100 rows. Of course processing (and grouping) 81922 rows takes longer than just retrieving 100 rows.

Comment: @user3207838 Selecting 100 rows is totally diferent operation than goruping-aggregation joined-tables and limit the output. It's just like you're comparing two diferent queries and are dissapoint by execution time. Just like you could take `select * from table_a' and `select 1` and be suprise that second is quicker.

Comment: Alright, but is there a way to make this query faster?

Comment: @user3207838 Please read https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and add table and index definitions.

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind the first query? The combination `order by caller_id ASC, call_time ASC LIMIT 100;` seems not correct.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko The reason we are doing the LIMIT 100 is because of a paging system. Since loading all rows would overload the UI, we only retrieve 100 items at a time. The next query will be OFFSET 100 LIMIT 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to select to 100 rows from table `calls` and then join and aggregate `calls_statistics`.

Something like:

```
WITH top_calls as (SELECT c.*
FROM calls AS c
ORDER BY caller_id ASC, call_time ASC 
LIMIT 100)
SELECT c.*,
array_agg(cs.mean) AS statistics_means
FROM top_calls AS c
LEFT JOIN calls_statistics AS cs ON c.calls_id = cs.calls_id
GROUP BY c.calls_id
order by caller_id ASC, call_time ASC;
```

It will give you exactly the same output as your first query.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing queries without all the info and live system may be a bit hard but I'm gonna take a shot at this. You can move the limit to a subquery and it should work much faster.

```
SELECT c.*,
array_agg(cs.mean) AS statistics_means
FROM 
  (SELECT *
   FROM calls AS c
   ORDER BY caller_id ASC, call_time ASC 
   LIMIT 100) AS c
LEFT JOIN calls_statistics AS cs ON c.calls_id = cs.calls_id
GROUP BY c.calls_id;
```